# How to prevent fragment detached in bottom navigation bar just like the NavigationAdvancedSample?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation-graph

I have two question from the [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample), which is the sample android repository.

### 1

I found out that `title` fragment isn't detached while user moved from `title` fragment to the other fragment such as `leaderboad` fragment(or `register` fragment). But I don't know which code from the repository prevent detachment of the title fragment. You can see that the home fragment(which is same with title fragment) isn't detached when user come back to the title fragment.
[image]
But from my code, the fragment is detached when user came back to the fragment from the other fragment just like the below picture.
[image]

### 2

At the same repository, `register` fragment is detached when user move from `register` fragment to `leaderboard` fragment or `home` fragment. But I can't understand how the input data at the Edittext isn't removed. There aren't any viewmodel, but how can the text at the EditText isn't removed when user leave the fragment.

Comment: I tested the 2.6.0 but still facing this issue ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version of the jetpack navigation.
Since I was using the navigation version as 2.3.5, the navigation was detaching.
The fragment was not detached from 2.4.0-alpha1 version. (I didn't check the other version.)